# error when mongoose connect database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, express

I have a problem when connect to database by mongoose.

 when i used this code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/goaljuice');
```

then I got problem.

 This is my problem

```
TypeError: Object function Mongoose() {
  this.connections = [];
  this.plugins = [];
  this.models = {};
  this.modelSchemas = {};
  this.options = {};
  this.createConnection(); // default connection
} has no method 'connect'
==================================
```

This is my structure folder:

```
-express_example
--app.js
--node_modules
------express, jade, mongodb, mongooses, stylus
--public
--router
--views
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;
```

try

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```